# Regression analysis of rank data

Tags: regression, logit, ranking

The dependent variable is Binary data and independent variables are ranks from 1 to 5. 
What method should I use in order to examine the relationship between these variables?

I am analyzing survey data from a questionnaire that asked about who did or didn't buy a certain product. Also it was asked what factors (price, quality, brand, ad and reference) influenced most and least, so respondent had to rank factors from 1 to 5.

Now, I want to run regression analysis with the ranking data to see which factors influenced most on their buying decision.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Can you explain / clarify further?

Comment: You talk about regression analysis but what output will you consider? Indeed, in your problem, the fact that the client has bought the item or not is meaningless as you only want to know which factors was the most influencial (for 0 or 1 indiscriminantly).  Moreover it can be tricky to determine which was the most influencial factor as you would need to compare preferences and it can lead to a paradox (Condorcet paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_paradox)